# Out of memory error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to see what is producing this error but I can´t see where is the problem. . I know that this error is produced because some images are too big so memory can´t be reserved for it. but I have been a couple of days trying to see what image is making this error to show but I can´t see it.Hope someone can help me. This is stack trace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
```

Comment: So you have *several* imageviews backed by images, one of them is throwing OOM, and you'd like to know which one? The OOM is not predictable; depending on the device's memory situation at any given run, it may crash on one attempt at allocation or at another.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev I have an image that is 1800x1800px, could it be that image that is causing the problem? I mean is 1800x1800px images be a factor of memory leak?

Comment: Your call stack looks like program's initial startup. A memory leak is unlikely; leaks usually manifest after some running time. It's probably the image. That said, modern Android devices should be able to handle a 12 MB image. Do you have *one* image that big, or several? Try looking at the heap state at crash time - any other big memory consumers?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev How can I look at the heap state at crash time?

Comment: Is this crash happening on your device, or on a user's one?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev on a user device. It is an error of the developer console panel. I have the device model only

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So it's a user crash. You are out of luck then. So you have a user with a cheap device that can't handle that image. :)

The best I can suggest:

- Create a downscaled version of the image
- Do a `try/catch` in `ActivityWorkout.onCreate`
- Capture the out-of-memory exception
- Set a "this is a low-memory device" flag in the settings (use `SharedPreferences`)
- Before loading the layout, read that flag
- Depending on its value, conditionally use either the full, or the downscaled version of the image

Comment: If I make a try catch in all the images instances, could I see later on the console which  image is causing the error ? Or why should I use try catch?

Comment: It doesn't matter which specific image is it crashing on; the point is that the memory footprint of your app, **as designed**, it too large for that user.

Comment: All you can see on the developer console is the message of the uncaught exception. So if you want to find out extra information from the user device, catch the exception and throw a new one (with the caught one as the inner exception), providing some diagnostic info in the message.